# How to apply product object in category to get product sigma algebra/topology/set systems?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, category-theory

Following is similar to [my earlier questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276632/is-my-understanding-of-product-sigma-algebra-or-topology-correct), but try to understand them from category theory. Mariano said it was possible in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21945/1281), but I don't know how.

An object $X$ is the product of a family $\{X\}_i, i \in I$ of objects iff there exist morphisms $\pi_i : X \to X_i$, such that for every object $Y$ and a $I$-indexed family of morphisms $f_i : Y \to X_i$ there exists a unique morphism $f : Y \to X$ such that the following diagrams commute for all $i \in I$:

[image]

When applying that definition to  set systems $(E_i, \mathcal{B}_i), i \in I$ of the same type $\theta$, to get their product set system $\mathcal{B}$ on $E= \prod_{i \in I} E_i$, I was wondering how that leads to 
$$\mathcal{B}=\theta \left(\left\{\text{$\prod_{i    \in I}B_i$,  where
    $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i, B_i=E_i$ for all    but finitely many $i \in I$}\right\}\right),$$
where $\theta(\cdot)$ means taking the smallest set system of the type $\theta$ containing $\cdot$.

Can it be 
$$\mathcal{B}=\theta\left(\left\{\text{$\prod_{i    \in I}B_i$,  where
    $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i, B_i=E_i$ at least for all    but one $i \in I$}\right\}\right),$$
instead?

Examples of product systems are product sigma algebras, product topology, and product of set systems defined to be closed under union only.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It should originally be rather the "*all but one $i$*" version as you suggested, because the point is that each individual projection $\pi_i$ has to be a morphism in the given category.

Therefore, in case of systems closed under union only, I have doubts that the former means the same, because it is an application of *finite intersection* only.